# Exporting result of eye reasoner query into a file

Tags: rdf, reasoning, n3

I use **Eye Reasoner** as a reasoning engine for a set of facts and rules in **N3** format. My question is how can I save the result of the **Eye reasoner** query into a file to use in the next step of my system?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that **Eye Reasoner** does not have the ability to save the result into a file. So, I handled it using `os.system()` function in *Python* which runs a terminal command and has the ability to save the result into a file.